# Check if RadComboBox SelectedItem is null

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

I am trying to verify if the SelectedItem of a RadComboBox is null using the following code:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RadComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text))
{
    //Do something
}
```

However, when the SelectedItem IS null, this code throws a NullReferenceException... the very thing I was trying to check for.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460754/how-to-check-whether-the-item-in-the-combo-box-is-selected-or-not-in-c) question which describes how to check if a ComboBox is null, but Telerik's RadComboBox does not have a "SelectedText" property.

How can rewrite this simple code to check if the RadComboBox has an item selected or not?

Comment: If you're worried about `SelectedItem` being null, why didn't you check if it was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check `SelectedItem` for null and then check its `Text` property like:

```
if (RadComboBox1.SelectedItem != null && 
    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RadComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text))
```

If there is no item selected then `SelectedItem` would be null and accessing its property `Text` would cause NRE.

Your current check is not checking for `SelectedItem` being null, instead it is only checking if the property `Text` is Null or WhiteSpace.